# Why did it take so long for Jensen's inequality?

Tags: mathematics, calculus

Why did it take so long for Jensen's inequality?
Jensen's inequality (compared with Lagrange multipliers, etc.) is based on comparatively elementary part of calculus. Still it was proven in 1906.
Is it at all possible that someone might have gotten it but did not publish it ?

Comment: Perhaps because the definition of "convex function" did not exist prior to 1905.  Thus, it took Jensen only one year to come up with this!

Answer (score 2):

The history behind Jensen's inequality is actually quite a long and difficult story. There is even a [thesis](http://prr.hec.gov.pk/Thesis/2306S.pdf) written on the subject by Rabia Bibi (2013).

In 1875 the following inequality was proven by J. Grolous:

$$f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}\right) \leq \frac1n\left(f(x_1)+f(x_2)+\cdots+f(x_n)\right)$$

for all convex functions $f$ and $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$ real numbers.

In 1889 the following inequality was proven by O. Hölder:

$$f\left(p_1x_1+p_2x_2+\cdots+p_nx_n\right) \leq p_1f(x_1)+p_2f(x_2)+\cdots+p_nf(x_n)$$

for all convex functions $f$ and $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$ real numbers and $p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_n$ positive real numbers such that $p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_n=1$.

The [1906 paper of Jensen](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~suvrit/teach/papers/1906_jensen_sur_les_fonctions_convexes_et_les_inegalites_entre_valeurs_moyennes.pdf) shows another result on integrals, in addition to the result on sums. This states, according to Bibi (2013):

$$g\left(\frac{\int_a^b f(t) \mathrm{d}t}{b-a} \right) \leq \frac{\int_a^b g(f(t)) \mathrm{d}t}{b-a}$$

with $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $g$ an integrable convex function and $f$ an integrable function.

All of these are sometimes called the Jensen inequality.